# Accessing td inner values inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am using the following to get all the table value entries.

```
var table = document.getElementById('mytable');

for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < 3; r++) {
    for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
        alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

However, this is returning

`<input type="text" value="xyz">`

Can anyone please tell how to alert 'xyz'

Comment: r u getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Nope, each entry in the table is <input type="text" value="xyz"> which is echoing. I want the access to xvz.

Comment: Because you are reading the html of the cell. It is doing exactly what you told. You need to access the form element in the cell. Look into `getElementsByTagName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have an input field inside the table cell
Try this:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('mytable');

for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < 3; r++) {
  for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
    alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value);
  }
}
```

```html
<TABLE id="mytable">
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <input value="test1">
    </TD>
    <TD>
      <input value="test2">
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <input value="test3">
    </TD>
    <TD>
      <input value="test4">
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Thanks, small change, its <td class="alt"><input type="text"
             value="<c:out value="${user.value}" />"></input></td> and this is inside a forloop

Comment: Um @rafavinu inputs do not have a </input> closing tag.